# How to design JTable within JScrollPane in NetBeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, matisse

I have created a JTable and enclosed it in a JScrollPane. Now when I try to select the table, the scrollpane is selected. I have no clue how to select the table which is inside this scrollpane. I am using Netbeans 6.9. How can I select this table?

Comment: What do you mean select the table?  Can you post the code?

Comment: By 'selecting' I mean to highlight the table visually in matisse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Netbeans..(design view)Inspector window will help you to select an individual component easily..it displays the tree view of the components placed...

If inspector window is not activated select
window->navigating->inspector...to activate it

hope this helps...